# How to plot a 3D graph of a difficult transcendental equation?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

i need to create this plot from an article,
[image]

using this equation

[image]

where

[image]

and

[image]

here rho2/rho0 is kept = 2,  c2= 0.7c0, va= 0.4c0 and c1 vary such that this equation is satisfied

[image]

i am very confused since i am a new here on mathematica but reading other posts i found out that this can be done using contour plot, can someone please help me out?

Edit,
here is the equation in mathematica, i made kx0 be x by writing x/k instead of x0 and named omegakc0 omega/(k*c0), i wrote omega= omegakc0*(k*c0) to make it spawn in the equation instead of omega since the z axis is in terms of this ratio

```
rho20 = 2
c2 = 0.7*c0
va = 0.4*c0
rho21=rho20/rho10
c1 = (rho21*c2^2)^(1/2)
omega=omegakc0*k*c0
ct = (c0^2*va^2/(c0^2 + va^2))^(1/2)
m1 = (k^2 - omega^2/c1^2)^(1/2)
m2 = (k^2 - omega^2/c2^2)^(1/2)
m0 = (( (k^2*va^2 - omega^2)*(k^2*c0^2 - omega^2) )/ ( (c0^2 + 
     va^2)*(k^2*ct^2 - omega^2)))^(1/2)
zero[omegakc0_, rho10_, x_] = 
omega^4*m0^2 + 1/rho10 * m1 * 1/rho20 *m2 *(k^2*va^2 - omega^2)^2 - 
1/2*m0*omega^2*(k^2*va^2 - omega^2)*(1/rho10*m1 + 
 1/rho20*m2)*(Tanh[m0*x/k] + Coth[m0*x/k])
```

[image]

Comment: Please type your equations in mathematica.

Comment: Hi yarchik, i wrote the equations in mathematica

Comment: In Mathematica (builtin) functions start with a capital letter. You need to type `Tanh` and `Coth`. It seems that `k` is not defined anywhere. When you have a well-defined function `zero[a, b, c]` you can simply do `ContourPlot3D[zero[a, b, c] == 0, {a, aMin, aMax}, {b, bMin, bMax}, {c, cMin, cMax}]`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, nope k is not defined, it should simplify or something (not really sure how) since the quantities on the axis are defined in term of it

Comment: In that case you made a mistake. I just spotted that for the square root you wrote `x^1/2`. However, this evaluates to `(x^1)/2`. You can either write `x^(1/2)` or `Sqrt[x]`. But this does not fix the `k` dependence issue.

Comment: Hi, i corrected the mistake, what should i do about the k?

Comment: I just realised that the "zero" equation factors into a k-dependent and a k-independent part. If you plot the k-independent part using `ContourPlot3D` you get something similar to the figure from the article.

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: `Simplify` can be used to simplify expressions.

Comment: With what assumption should i use it? Do i just put Simplify before the expression of equation zero?

Comment: `zero[omegakc0_, rho10_, x_] = Simplify[..., Assumptions -> k > 0]` (where `...` is the code in your post) should work.

Comment: Hey i did it, now i just have to change the axis or something, thanks for the help, i actually found the whole zero equations factors with a k^6*c0^4 so i divided by it and got it, do you know how to change colors and put labels?

Answer (score 1):

```
fun = Solve[Tanh[a] + Coth[a] == b, a]

{{a -> ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTanh[1/2 (b - Sqrt[-4 + b^2])] + I \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {a -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    ArcTanh[1/2 (b + Sqrt[-4 + b^2])] + I \[Pi] C[1], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

[image: output ArcTanh]

is essential for the solution. So there are two parts of the solution. b is
the rest of the equations stuffed on the other side of the equality.

```
ContourPlot3D[(\[Omega]^4 ((k^2 Subscript[v, 
       A]^2 - -\[Omega]^2) (k^2 Subscript[c, 
       0]^2 - \[Omega]^2))/((Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, 
      A]^2) (k^2 (Subscript[c, 0]^2 Subscript[v, A]^2)/(
       Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, A]^2) - \[Omega]^2)) + 
  1/y Sqrt[k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(Sqrt[2 y (0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2])^2] 1/
   2 Sqrt[k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2] (k^2 Subscript[v, 
      A]^2 - \[Omega]^2)^2)/(
 1/2 Sqrt[((k^2 Subscript[v, A]^2 - \[Omega]^2) (k^2 Subscript[c, 
      0]^2 - \[Omega]^2))/((Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, 
     A]^2) (k^2 (Subscript[c, 0]^2 Subscript[v, A]^2)/(
      Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, 
       A]^2) - \[Omega]^2))] \[Omega]^2 (k^2 Subscript[v, 
     A]^2 - \[Omega]^2) (1/y Sqrt[
     k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(Sqrt[2 y (0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2])^2] + 
    1/2 Sqrt[k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2])), {\[Omega], 
  0, 0.4}, {y, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 2.5}]
```

[image: output of Contourplot3D]

This looks despite the fact that the same volume is used rather alike.

[image: second output slitely turned around]

Both graphics outputs show up there is mathematical very much to do on case separation and ordering.

To go the next step there some more information necessary. Most critical to match the presented graphics surface in the question is x0 and va.

So brute force gives:

```
ContourPlot3D[\[Omega]^4 ((k^2 Subscript[v, 
        A]^2 - -\[Omega]^2) (k^2 Subscript[c, 
        0]^2 - \[Omega]^2))/((Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, 
       A]^2) (k^2 (Subscript[c, 0]^2 Subscript[v, A]^2)/(
        Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, A]^2) - \[Omega]^2)) + 
   1/y Sqrt[k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(Sqrt[2 y (0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2])^2] 1/
    2 Sqrt[k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2] (k^2 Subscript[v,
        A]^2 - \[Omega]^2)^2 - 
   1/2 Sqrt[((k^2 Subscript[v, A]^2 - \[Omega]^2) (k^2 Subscript[c, 
        0]^2 - \[Omega]^2))/((Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, 
       A]^2) (k^2 (Subscript[c, 0]^2 Subscript[v, A]^2)/(
        Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, 
         A]^2) - \[Omega]^2))] \[Omega]^2 (k^2 Subscript[v, 
       A]^2 - \[Omega]^2) (1/y Sqrt[
       k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(Sqrt[2 y (0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2])^2] + 
      1/2 Sqrt[
       k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2]) (Tanh[\[Sqrt](1/
          2 Sqrt[((k^2 Subscript[v, A]^2 - \[Omega]^2) (k^2 Subscript[
              c, 0]^2 - \[Omega]^2))/((Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[
             v, 
             A]^2) (k^2 (Subscript[c, 0]^2 Subscript[v, A]^2)/(
              Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, 
               A]^2) - \[Omega]^2))] \[Omega]^2 (k^2 Subscript[v, 
             A]^2 - \[Omega]^2) (1/y Sqrt[
             k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(Sqrt[
               2 y (0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2])^2] + 
            1/2 Sqrt[k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2]))] + 
      Coth[\[Sqrt](1/
          2 Sqrt[((k^2 Subscript[v, A]^2 - \[Omega]^2) (k^2 Subscript[
              c, 0]^2 - \[Omega]^2))/((Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[
             v, A]^2) (k^2 (Subscript[c, 0]^2 Subscript[v, A]^2)/(
              Subscript[c, 0]^2 + Subscript[v, 
               A]^2) - \[Omega]^2))] \[Omega]^2 (k^2 Subscript[v, 
             A]^2 - \[Omega]^2) (1/y Sqrt[
             k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(Sqrt[
               2 y (0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2])^2] + 
            1/2 Sqrt[k^2 - \[Omega]^2/(0.7 Subscript[c, 0])^2]))]) == 
  0, {\[Omega], 0, 0.4}, {y, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 2.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {\[Omega], Subscript[\[Rho], 1]/Subscript[\[Rho], 0], 
   k}]
```

[image: complete solution]

The difference are for shure from the selection of the plus/minus arms of the square roots so often taken. Common is the lower surface with the characteristic slope changes.

Have fun.

Comment: thanks for the help :) have a nice day